# How to setup redis service with django

Tags: django, redis, continuous-integration, github-actions, devops

I am creating a django CI pipeline using github actions but I am getting the following error.

```
Found 23 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
EEEEEEEEEEEEs..........
======================================================================
ERROR: test_account_str (blog.tests.test_models.TestAccount)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 699, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 700, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 970, in _connect
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

My github actions workflow file looks like this

```
    services:
      redis_db:
        image: redis
        # env:
        #   CELERY_BROKER_URL: ${{env.CELERY_BROKER_URL}}
        #   CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: ${{env.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND}}
        #   REDIS_HOST: localhost
        #   REDIS_PORT: 6379
        # ports:
        #   - 6379:6379

        options: >-
          --health-cmd "redis-cli ping"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
```

Kindly assist me in identifying the issue.

I tried to run the job in a container and directly in the runner but the error still persists

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-redis-service-containers? Your host value needs to be correct.